# Locked myself out of SSH with UFW in EC2 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ufw

I have an EC2 Instance with Ubuntu.
I used `sudo ufw enable` and after only allow the mongodb port

```
sudo ufw allow 27017
```

When the ssh connection broke, I can´t reconnect

Comment: The below answers give "the cure". Just thought I'd mention "the prevention". Before enabling ufw, ensure there's a rule in there for SSH. You can do this with: ``sudo ufw allow OpenSSH``.

Answer (score 142):

**# Update**

Easiest way is to update the instance's user data

- Stop your instance
- Right click (windows) or ctrl + click (Mac) on the instance to open context menu, then go to `Instance Settings` -> `Edit User Data` or select the instance and go to `Actions` -> `Instance Settings` -> `Edit User Data`

  If you're still on the old AWS console, select the instance, go to `Actions` -> `Instance Settings` -> `View/Change User Data`

And paste this

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0
--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]
--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"
#!/bin/bash
ufw disable
iptables -L
iptables -F
--//
```

- Once added, restart the instance and ssh should work. The userdata disables ufw if enabled and also flushes any iptable rules blocking ssh access

Source [here](https://linuxbyimraan.co.za/2018/12/01/accidentally-enabled-ufw-on-your-ubuntu-instance-and-cant-ssh-as-a-result/)

**# Old Answer**

Detach and fix the volume of the problem instance using another instance

- Launch a new instance (recovery instance).
- Stop the original instance (DO NOT TERMINATE)
- Detach the volume (problem volume) from the original instance
- Attached it to the recovery instance as /dev/sdf.
- Login to the recovery instance via ssh/putty
- Run `sudo lsblk` to display attached volumes and confirm the name of the problem volume. It usually begins with `/dev/xvdf`. Mine is `/dev/xvdf1`
- Mount problem volume.

  ```
    $ sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt
    $ cd /mnt/etc/ufw
  ```
- Open `ufw` configuration file

  ```
    $ sudo vim ufw.conf
  ```
- Press i to edit the file.
- Change `ENABLED=yes` to `ENABLED=no`
- Type Ctrl-C and type :wq to save the file.
- Display content of ufw conf file using the command below and ensure that `ENABLED=yes` has been changed to `ENABLED=no`

  ```
    $ sudo cat ufw.conf
  ```
- Unmount volume

  ```
    $ cd ~
    $ sudo umount /mnt
  ```
- Detach problem volume from recovery instance and re-attach it to the original instance as /dev/sda1.
- Start the original instance and you should be able to log back in.

Source: [here](https://ubuntuaws.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/locked-myself-out-of-ssh-port-ubuntu-aws-server-using-ufw/)

Comment: You are an awesome man. This should be accepted the answer. One thing to keep in mind while creating a new instance (recovery instance) make sure the region and zone are the same as the original instance. The zone can be selected in Configure Instance Details page -> Availability Zone.

Comment: The path for the new AWS panel is: `Actions` -> `Instance Settings` -> `Edit User Data` . The editable field is only visible whenever the instance is properly stopped.

Comment: The updated one is the answer. Works like a charm and a life saver.

Answer (score 73):

I have the same problem and found out that this steps works:

1- Stop your instance

2- Go to `Instance Settings` -> `View/Change user Data`

**UPDATE: PATH ON NEW AWS CONSOLE UI**

Right click on your `Stopped` instance -> `Instance Settings` -> `Edit User Data`

3- Paste this on the option `Modify user data as text` and Save

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0
--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]
--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"
#!/bin/bash
ufw disable
iptables -L
iptables -F
--//
```

4- Start your instance

Hope it works for you!

Comment: This worked like a charm. Don't forget to change the public ip address (of your Ec2 instance) in the ssh command.

Answer (score 18):

- Launch another EC2 server instance
  The best way to accomplish this is use EC2’s “Launch More Like This” feature. This will ensure that the OS type, security group and other attributes are the same thus saving a bit of setup time.
- Stop the problem instance
- Detach volume from problem instance
- Attach volume to new instance

> Note: Newer Linux kernels may rename your devices to /dev/xvdf through
>   /dev/xvdp internally, even when the device name entered is /dev/sdf
>   through /dev/sdp.

- Mount the volume

> ```
> cd ~
> mkdir lnx1
> sudo mount /dev/xvdf ./lnx1
> ```

- Disable UFW

> ```
> cd lnx1
> sudo vim ufw.conf
> ```

Now find ENABLED=yes and change it to ENABLED=no.

- Detach volume

Be sure to unmount the volume first:

```
sudo umount ./lnx1/
```

- Reattach the volume to /dev/sda1 on our problem instance
- Boot problem instance
- Reassign elastic IP address if necessary
- Delete the temporary instance and its associated volume

Hola !! 
you are good  go.

Comment: If you're getting "Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/sda1)" set device to '/dev/sda1' instead of '/dev/sdf' while you're reattaching the volume to old instance.

Comment: ufw.conf filepath is ~/etc/ufw/ufw.conf

Answer (score 16):

Other approaches didn't work for me. My EC2 instance is based on Bitnami image. Attaching volume to another instance didn't work because of marketplace locks.

So instead stop the problem instance and paste this script in instanceSettings > view-change user data.

**This approach do not require detaching the volume so it's more straight forward as compared to other ones.**

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0
--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]
--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"
#!/bin/bash
ufw disable
iptables -L
iptables -F
--//
```

Must stop instance before pasting this, after this start your instance and you should be able to ssh.

Comment: How to find out if my image is based on bitnami image?

Comment: Just as an FYI, Don't forget to change the public ip address (of your Ec2 instance) in the ssh command.

Comment: Awesome solution. Works! IP was changed and I had to add the new IP to my Route53 DNS settings

Comment: Dynamic IP changes when instance is restarted, a static IP could be used to make it stay same after restart.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old question but I fixed mine by adding a command in View/Change User Data using `bootcmd`

I first stopped my instance

Then I added this in User Data

```
#cloud-config
bootcmd:
 - cloud-init-per always fix_broken_ufw_1 sh -xc "/usr/sbin/service ufw stop >> /var/tmp/svc_$INSTANCE_ID 2>&1 || true" 
 - cloud-init-per always fix_broken_ufw_2 sh -xc "/usr/sbin/ufw disable>> /var/tmp/ufw_$INSTANCE_ID 2>&1 || true"
```

**#Note: My instance is Ubuntu**

Comment: Wow. Only this solution worked for me. Other answers were mostly about fixing the instance to the previous state (before enabling ufw). This is the only one deals about connecting via ssh despite enabling ufw. thanks.

Comment: @ADB  Could you explain what these 3 lines of code do?

Comment: How did you guys come up with these kind of solutions? What kind of experience is needed?

Comment: This one did it for me! Ubuntu 18.04.2, ec2 t2.micro. Internet researching skills, and lots of AWS Whitepaper reading will go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

## Here's a little more *extended version* of the user-data-script thing:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
set -x
USERNAME="ubuntu"
ls -Al
ls -Al /home
ls -Al /home/${USERNAME}
ls -Al /home/${USERNAME}/.ssh
sudo cat /home/${USERNAME}/.ssh/authorized_keys
ls -Al /etc/ssh
ls -ld /etc/ssh

sudo grep -vE '^$|^#' /etc/hosts.*
sudo sed -i -e 's/^\([^#].*\)/# \1/g' /etc/hosts.deny
sudo sed -i -e 's/^\([^#].*\)/# \1/g' /etc/hosts.allow
sudo grep -vE '^$|^#' /etc/hosts.*
sed '/^$\|^#/d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

chown -v root:root /home
chmod -v 755 /home
chown -v ${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} /home/${USERNAME} -R
chmod -v 700 /home/${USERNAME}
chmod -v 700 /home/${USERNAME}/.ssh
chmod -v 600 /home/${USERNAME}/.ssh/authorized_keys

sudo tail /var/log/auth.log
sudo ufw status numbered
sudo ufw disable
sudo iptables -F
sudo service iptables stop
sudo service sshd restart
sudo service sshd status -l
--//
```

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for 2 days I found few easy alternatives, here are those:

- Use AWS session manager to connect without ssh ([yt tutorial](https://youtu.be/SwSEmvWMuMU))
- Use EC2 serial console

Use either of these approaches to get into the machine and later you can change the ufw or ssh keys ...etc

Comment: it's fine if you have the `ubuntu` password (which I believe is disabled by default)

Answer (score 1):

### **Use Session Manager to connect to your EC2 (No SSH required)**

To disable UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) in the terminal, you can use the following command:

```
    sudo ufw disable
```

This will turn off the firewall and all incoming traffic will be allowed. It is recommended to only disable the firewall temporarily and enable it again once you're done with your task.