# unable to connect ssh after run command sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ufw

Anybody please help me

Im unable to connect my server after run this command sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'.

In aws is there any option to undo this changes or anything else

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

1. Stop the running EC2 instance
2. Detach its `/dev/sda1` volume (let's call it volume A)
3. Start the new t1.micro EC2 instance, create it on the same subnet, otherwise you will have to terminate the instance and create it again.
4. Attach volume A to the new micro instance, as `/dev/xvdf`
5. SSH to the new micro instance and mount volume A to `/mnt/tmp`
6. Disable UFW by setting `ENABLED=no` in `/mnt/tmp/etc/ufw/ufw.conf`
7. Exit
8. Terminate micro instance
9. Detach volume A from it
10. Attach volume A back to the main instance as /dev/sda1 Start the main instance
11. Login as before

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

If you have server backup, try restoring to that backup.

If not, try looking at [AWS Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html).

Please post your error or logs upon connecting. Can't help much without logs.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for 2 days I found few easy alternatives, here are those:

- Use AWS session manager to connect with out ssh or key ([yt](https://youtu.be/SwSEmvWMuMU))
- Use EC2 serial console
- Update the user instance details ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929267/locked-myself-out-of-ssh-with-ufw-in-ec2-aws))

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation, you just need create a new session to use EC2 terminal.

1. First create a new role permissions, you can find instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html. OBS: on "Resource" tag change from "key-name" to "*".
2. You need link this IAM role to your EC2 instance Actions > Security > Modify IAM Role and and choose the role you created in step 1, after that, you will able to access your instance from EC2 terminal.
3. access session manager: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/session-manager/start-session?region=us-east-1, remember to change to your instance region and click on button "start session" above "next" button.
4. run command "sudo ufw disable" and restart system from terminal or from aws instance.
5. now, you have access to your server again.

this helped me, I hope this will helps you.