# Unable to reach EC2 instance after setting up NGINX

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am unable to reach EC2 instance after installing NGINX on that EC2 instance didn't get why this happen I just run below commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
sudo ufw app list
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
sudo ufw status
```

before installing NGINX i am able to take SSH connection of EC2 but after doing this I am not reach to EC2 i cross check everything

SG Inbounds has enable 22 port [trying with all of three MyIp,Custom,Anywhere], 
VPC has internet gateway which is properly bind

is there anything that i left? 
or

```
 "sudo ufw enable"
```

command run on my EC2 is creates the issue

Answer (score 14):

1. Stop the running EC2 instance
2. Detach its `/dev/sda1` volume
3. Start another EC2 instance, it should be on the same subnet
4. Attach volume to the new micro instance, as `/dev/xvdf`
5. SSH to the new instance and mount the volume to `/mnt/tmp`

   `sudo fdisk -l # check volumes and find the volume we wanna mount, in my case it's  /dev/xvdf1
   sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp
   sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt/tmp`
6. Disable UFW by setting `ENABLED=no` in `/mnt/tmp/etc/ufw/ufw.conf`

   `cd
   sudo nano /mnt/tmp/etc/ufw/ufw.conf`
7. Exit
8. Terminate the new instance
9. Detach the volume from it
10. Attach volume back to the main instance as `/dev/sda1` Start the main instance
11. Login as before
12. Enable ssh connections

    `sudo ufw allow ssh
     sudo ufw enable`

Kudos to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49432706

Comment: Anytime) @kirtan403

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should allow SSH connections before enabling the firewall so;

Execute

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Before

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: I am unable to reach EC2 so now how can I allow ssh is there any other way and is it the issue of ufw i am not sure about this?

Comment: i'm not sure aws provides console access. if it doesn't you can destroy and recreate the ec2 instance.