# SSH into EC2 instance timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm trying to SSH into a EC2 instance. It worked previously, but stopped working all of a sudden. Now, I'm getting the error `port 22: Operation timed out`
. My inbound security rules allow all IP addresses for SSH on port 22.

I tried creating a new instance from an image and downloading a new key, but I was still not able to SSH into it the new instance.

What could be the problem here?

My API is running on the server when I try to go to the public ip of the instance.
[image]

SOLUTION: ufw firewall did not allow ssh. Solution: [Locked myself out of SSH with UFW in EC2 AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929267/locked-myself-out-of-ssh-with-ufw-in-ec2-aws/41929843)

Comment: Can you check the instances system log and screenshot? (through EC2 console, right click -> Instance Settings)

Comment: Not sure what to look for in the log, but the log looks ok. It is showing the keys etc. The last line says ip-.... login: Screenshot also has that login statement.

Comment: Are you running the instance in a default VPC or a public subnet of a custom vpc?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the instances log / screenshot look okay. We'll assume that it's a network issue somewhere. First step would be to create an AWS Flowlog for your VPC. Flowlogs allow to see if traffic is blocked by a security group or something like that. If your instance is not receiving traffic due to a SG you'll see it in a flowlog.

To create a flowlog go to the VPC console > VPC's and select your VPC. IN the lower frame go to the flowlog tab and select create a flowlog. I would suggest you filter for "REJECT" only because otherwise it'll fill up fast. You can publish it to CloudWatch and take a look at it.

Flowlogs are delivered per network interface, so you'll need to check your EC2 instance for the relevent ENI-id.

Comment: Where do I specify the ENI-id?  I am setting up the flow log now- EDIT: Ok, I think I see what you mean

Comment: Ok, so I created the flowlog with max aggregation interval 10 min. It is active in the VPC console.

Comment: Cool, first step is just try to log in and see if any reject / accept messages appear

Comment: Ok. What do I now do to use this log? When I try to SSH nothing happens in the log.

Comment: It says "no events found" in the log group I created.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I think the ufw firewall on my apache server does not allow for SSH. I forgot to run `sudo ufw allow ssh` while I was still logged on the server..

Comment: Posted solution in EDIT.