# Failed to connect to EC2 ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to an ec2 ubuntu instance and I am getting a connection timed out error. :
EC2 Instance Connect is unable to connect to your instance. Ensure your instance network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance

I have checked the subnet routing table and its set to internet-gateway, the network security group allows TCP http/s and ssh connections.

the connection to the instance was working fine initially, but when trying at a later point I am getting this error.

While the site/apps hosted on the instance are accessible via browser, access to instance itself is not possible.

And I launched a new ec2 instance based on the template of the 1st ec2 and I am able to connect to 2nd instance.

Comment: Did you try to reboot the instance from the web console? Maybe the instance connect agent stopped running on the EC2 instance for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had enable ufw in the my instance and hence got locked out.

Answer is explained in the below question.

[Locked myself out of SSH with UFW in EC2 AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929267/locked-myself-out-of-ssh-with-ufw-in-ec2-aws)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).